# Understanding n-MOSFET specs

Tags: mosfet

I'm using an [FQP30N06L](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/General/FQP30N06L.pdf) to dim a 1W LED being driven by a constant current supply. This MOSFET has a \$V_{GS}\$ threshold of 2.5V, which is why I picked it since I'm driving it from a 3.3V PWM pin on an Arduino. It works fine when the drain-source voltage is under 6V or so. When it gets to 9V, it stops turning on. I always understood N-channel MOSFETS to be the way to go in this scenario precisely because they can be driven from a low voltage relative to drain (as opposed to having to drive down from a high one for a P-channel). What am I missing? What parameter should I be looking at to understand?

\$V_{GS}\$ chart for reference:

[image]

Schematic of how I'm using it for reference:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdV7QS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In the schematic above, M1 is getting stuck off, but I can turn it on by bringing Gate to Drain

Answer (score 3):

You need resistors in series with the LEDs.

That is not a 3.3V logic-level MOSFET and cannot reliably be driven fully on with 3.3V. It is specified at 5 and 10V so it's best to drive it with at least 5V. If you don't have 5V available, you might want to buy a different MOSFET.

All Vgs(th) guarantees you is that with 2.5V you'll have at least 250uA flowing with gate tied to drain.

Rds(on) is guaranteed to be < 45m\$\Omega\$ with 5V drive at 25'C (a fair bit higher when hot).

[image]

Your graph above is a typical characteristic and not something you can depend on except perhaps the general shape.

Comment: sigh. thanks. also - LEDs are 1W, driven off a constant current supply, hence no resistors. Really irritating since SparkFun advertises these as logic level. Trust but verify, I guess.

Comment: @kolosy "LEDs are 1W, driven off a constant current supply" um that can make a huge difference to what the mosfet is going to do to...

Comment: @Trevor care to elaborate? I did mention the 1W part in the post. Will add the CC part.

Comment: @kolosy if you  have a constant current driver trying to deliver NmA down that chain you may find discharging the gate drain capacitor rather difficult.

Comment: @Trevor ...there is not enough gate capacitance for the CC drive to be an issue.

Comment: @JackCreasey maybe maybe not. Not sure what the CC will do while it's switching over though, depending on the driver the voltage may spike pretty high or the thing might even cut out.

Comment: Well, 5V is logic level, just not yours. The schematic symbol you used is for a 9V constant voltage supply. There is a [different symbol](http://videomodel.ecam.be/compo/isource/isource_2d.png) for a constant current supply. CC supply may be why you are seeing strange things happen.

Comment: Thanks - CL doesn't seem to have that one (at least not that I could find).

Comment: It's right beside the voltage one.

Comment: Thanks - was looking for the overlapped circles, missed the obvious one.